# Laravel + dompdf + tinymce not generate pdf

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-5.8

I have a problem generating pdf from dompdf from the textarea tinymce field. I keep receiving the timeout message maximum time 60 seconds. below is my controller code.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

```
public function zf_pdf($id)
{

   $przedsiebiorca = \App\Przedsiebiorca::findOrFail($id);
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('przedsiebiorca.print_cars', ['przedsiebiorca' => $przedsiebiorca]);
   $dok = DB::table('dok_przed')->where('id_przed' , $przedsiebiorca->id)->get();
   $pisma = DB::table('pisma')->where('id_przed' , $przedsiebiorca->id)->get();

   $pdf = PDF::loadView('przedsiebiorca.pisma.zf_pdf', ['przedsiebiorca' => $przedsiebiorca,'dok'=> $dok, 'pisma' => $pisma] );

    return $pdf->download('pismo_zdolnosc_finansowa.pdf');

}
```

Below is the html code

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
     tinymce.init({
      selector: '#pismo',
      language: 'pl',
      readonly: 0,
      plugins: "print, autoresize"

    });

 </script>
```

```html
<div class="container" style="font-size: 14px;font-family: Arial;width:900px;">

  <div><a href="{{url('przedsiebiorca/pisma/zf_pdf', $przedsiebiorca->id)}}" target="_blank" role="button" class="btn btn-warning">Wydrukuj pismo w PDF</a></div>
  
     <div><img src="{{URL::asset('/img/starostwo.png')}}" alt="profile Pic" width="900px;"></div>
     <div><textarea class="form-control" id="pismo" name="uwagi" style="height: 100%;">
          @foreach($pisma as $ps)
            {{$ps->tresc}}
          @endforeach
    </textarea></div>

</div>
```

Comment: remove your foreach loop and try again. See if thats the issue

Comment: Try cranking your execution time way up and see what the output is after 10 minutes or so. It'll likely show you what's taking so long.

Comment: I have improved my controller and the pdf generates data, but the pdf only shows HTML code, not content. in the content field I have a longtext and it contains HTML code, e.g. <div> some text </div> etc. and it displays to me in pdf how to change it?